# How to Access RabbitMQ Server from another server/machine instead of localhost?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am working with ASP.NET Core Microservice. I have two ASP.NET Core Service (MS-1 and MS-2 where MS-1 is the publisher and MS-2 is the Consumer). I have implmented RabbitMQ with Masstransit for queue messaging.

The following code works fine when I try to access local machine rabbitMQ server. But it doesn't work when I try to access RabbitMQ server which is intalled on another machine. (i.e. 202.00.000.000:15672)

**MS-1 Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    // configure health checks for this bus instance
                    cfg.UseHealthCheck(provider);

                     cfg.Host("rabbitmq://localhost");

                    //cfg.Host("rabbitmq://202.00.000.000:15672");
                }));
            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

**MS-1 Publisher Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OrderController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBusControl _bus;

        public OrderController(IBusControl bus)
        {
            _bus = bus;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrder(Order order)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/order-queue");

            //Uri uri = new Uri("rabbitmq://202.00.000.000:15672/order-queue");

            var endPoint =  await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(uri);
            await endPoint.Send(order);

            return Ok("Success");
        }
    }
```

**MS-2 Consumer Controller**

```
public class OrderConsumer :
      IConsumer<Order>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Order> context)
        {
            var data = context.Message;
            // message received.
        }
    }
```

**MS-2 Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>();

                x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    // configure health checks for this bus instance
                    cfg.UseHealthCheck(provider);

                    cfg.Host("rabbitmq://localhost");
                    //cfg.Host("rabbitmq://202.00.000.000:15672");

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("order-queue", ep =>
                    {
                        ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                        ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));


                        ep.ConfigureConsumer<OrderConsumer>(provider);
                    });
                }));
            });




            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

Comment: The IP Address looks weird. And the standport would be 5672. 0 in the hostpart of a ipv4 address normally means a network and does not an address of a host.

Comment: I just replace the actually IP address with Zeros, to avoid any security issue

Answer (score 1):

try this:
`Uri uri = new Uri("rabbitmq://202.00.000.000:5672");`

Comment: It doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

With your configuration, using the address is the correct approach, but you must also specify a username/password combination other than `guest/guest`, since those credentials are *only* supported on `localhost`.

```cs
cfg.Host("202.00.000.000", h =>
{
    h.Username("some-user-not-guest");
    h.Password("password");
});
```

There is no need to build a URI, or any other format, just specify the host name or IP address.

Also, I'd suggest using the full host configuration on both services, with a username/password other than `guest`.

#### Bonus Answer

I've also updated your configuration to the latest syntax. `AddBus` will be deprecated at some point, you are using outdated configuration syntax.

##### MS-1 Startup

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
         cfg.Host("localhost");
    }));
});
```

##### MS-2 Startup

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("202.00.000.000", h =>
        {
            h.Username("some-user-not-guest");
            h.Password("password");
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("order-queue", ep =>
        {
            ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
            ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));

            ep.ConfigureConsumer<OrderConsumer>(context);
        });
    }));
});
```

Comment: I have tried the solution, but didn't work for me. It takes minuts when executing ` await endPoint.Send(order);`
As per the Documentation this can be a DNS issue. But I am not able to fix this issue by following their docs.
[link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#dns)

Comment: Standard network concerns should be checked. Firewall access, username/password, DNS/IP address, etc. The MassTransit configuration above shows how, you'll still have to make sure the network ports are open, etc.

Comment: When I try to Access 202.00.000.000:15672 from my local machine browser. It's accessable; I can see rabbitMQ Admin Portal. So IP address and Port is open and accessable over the internet. The only problem is that is not accessable from ASP.NET Core code that i have mentioned above

Comment: Accessible on your local machine browser is not the same as accessing your machine from another machine on the network/internet. And RabbitMQ uses 5672 for non-secure, and 5671 for secure AMQP connections. Your issue is more network/firewall/RabbitMQ than anything to do with MassTransit.